# modify part of a string in a string pointer

Tags: c

I have a character pointer, which has a string assigned to it. And I'm sure that the string is of 8 characters length. (Ex: SHIVA0BS) And it is also a fact that the last two letters are always going to be "BS". But I'm just going to double check it. Now I'd like to take the first 6 characters ("SHIVA0") and append it to something else, say ("SHIVA0NN") - how would I make it possible?

```
     #include<stdio.h>
     #include<stdlib.h>
     void main()
     {
     char *ptr, *new;
     ptr = "FECI00BS";
     strncpy(new,ptr,6);
     printf("%s",new);
     strcat(new,"NN");
     }
```

The above code is what I wrote. And I'm not sure why it is not working. I understand that my requirement is very trivial, but I tried printfs in between. I was able to find that (ptr+6) printed "BS", so that 6 is the length that I need. But this is still not working. Any help appreciated. I need the output in a string pointer. A new one is fine. But a string pointer.

P.S: Only C code please. No C++.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want:

```
sprintf(ptr+6, "NN");
```

That will modify your buffer to convert BS into NN. In this case you can get rid of the `new` variable.

EDIT

Try this. Notice the `char ptr[]` instead of `char* ptr`. By using `[]` instead of a pointer you are allocating the buffer on the stack. This allows you to write to the buffer.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

void main()
{
    char ptr[] = "FECI00BS";
    sprintf(ptr+6,"NN");
    printf(ptr);
}
```

Comment: I tried that as well, just now. Using code pad.org. Gives me segmentation fault. :(

Answer (score 2):

You didn't allocate memory to hold your new string

```
char * new = calloc(1, 10); // on heap
```

or

```
char new[10]; // on stack
memset(new, 0, sizeof(new)); // zero it
```

Comment: I tried that. It still gave me error. Not my desired output. :(

Answer (score 1):

You're not allocating memory for storing the strings.

You need to allocate memory for both *ptr and *new.

The bare minimum would be:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

int main()
{

    char *ptr, *new;
    new = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * 9);
    new = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * 9);
    ptr = "FECI00BS";
    strncpy(a,ptr,6);
    printf("%s",new);
    strcat(a,"NN");
    printf("%s",new);

}
```

You need 9 bytes (assuming your platform needs one byte per char) because of the End-Of-Line character, '\0', that needs to be present at the end of strings in order to use some string.h functions or print them correctly.

Also, read on why [you need to be careful with strncpy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_string_handling#Strcat.2Fstrcpy_replacements). Depending on your platform, you may have access to some newer, safer alternatives from the C standard.

Answer (score 0):

Just a few simple checks and `memcpy()`.

```
char *ShivaAppend(char *dest, const char *ptr, const char *suffix) {
  size_t len = strlen(ptr);
  if (len != 8) {
    return NULL;
  }
  if (strcmp(ptr, "BS") != 0) {
    return NULL;
  }
  len = strlen(suffix);
  if (len != 2) {
    return NULL;
  }
  memcpy(dest, ptr, 6);
  memcpy(&dest[6], suffix, 2);
  return dest;
}

...
char dest[9];
char *p = ShivaAppend(dest, "SHIVA0BS", "NN")
puts(p == NULL ? "fail", p);
```